# Add external jars to Eclipse plugin classpath

Tags: jar, eclipse-plugin, classpath

In the manifest file for an eclipse plugin its possible to add jar files and
folders to the classpath (on the *Runtime* tab).

In the root of my plugin I have a folder `lib` containing `a-1.0.1.jar`, `b-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. But only when I select each jar separately:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/a-1.0.1.jar,
 lib/b-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

...can they be used inside my project. Why is it not possible to add them to the classpath by adding the common root folder only:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/
```

?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Eclipse is based on OSGi, which is the platform providing `MANIFEST.MF` support to build plugins.

When you set values under `Bundle-ClassPath`, OSGi search into each one to find class files. So you can put folders containing Java packages and class files. When you put a jar file, it is uncompressed in memory and viewed by OSGi as a regular folder, still searching for class files.

Unfortunately, there is no way to load all jar from a folder. No wildcard mechanism or something like that is allowed here.